# Determining odd and even numbers in python

Tags: python, math, integer

I have this code but whenever I enter any number odd or even it says it is even (the indents may not be correct here but that's not the cause as they are in the program)...

```
import random
number1 = random.randint(1,6)
number2 = random.randint(1,6)
input("Ready for round one? Press enter key to begin!")
print("Player one, you rolled", number1, "and", number2)
number3 = number1 + number2
time.sleep(1)
print("This means your total is", number3)
time.sleep(1)
if number3 == ("1", "3", "5", "7", "9", "11"):
   print("However, you rolled an odd. -5 points for you!")
   p1score = number3 -5
else:
    print("Also.... YOU GOT AN EVEN! +10 Points!")
    p1score = number3 +10
time.sleep(1)
print("Player ones total is", p1score)
```

Comment: `number3` is an int. It's not equal to a sequence of strings.

Comment: Also, you're not adding 10 points to their score, you're setting their score equal to `number3 +10` (the number they rolled, plus 10). Similarly, `number3 -5`.

Comment: Also, you can't score a 1 by adding up two d6 dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if number3 % 2 != 0:
    print("However, you rolled an odd. -5 points for you!")
    p1score = number3 - 5
```

Replace your odd logic with this